# How do I post to facebook from my React app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, reactjs

Currently have an app with React on the Front end, and Rails on the back end. Want to post stuff to facebook. Any tips for tutorials that I could use?

Comment: Does Rails make any difference here?  Seems like a front end only type of situation unless you need to post "on be-half of the user" by authenticating and storing an access token.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create Facebook Share Button component fair easily by yourself. Just pass the URL you want to share to fb as a param in URL which is provided by Facebook:

```
`https://facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=${encodedURL}`
```

I've built a react component for you:

```
class FBShareButton extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
     url : this.props.url
    }
  }

  render(){
    let encodedURL = encodeURI(this.state.url);
    return(
      <a href={`https://facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=${encodedURL}`}>Share on Facebook</a>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <FBShareButton url={"https://stackoverflow.com"} />, document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Also check the demo [here](https://codepen.io/sivadass/pen/xPGxxZ?editors=1111).

Answer (score 0):

React + Facebook + Open Source = here's one option: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-facebook